# Special 3D environment system for a game

Tags: java, 3d, game-engine

So, I've been making this game for about 3 months, and it's frameworks are almost ready, but it's missing one thing: The visual part. The game's map system must be a 3D environment, but it's not a regular one, as this one's main idea is to build the map itself using mostly code rather than loading any other sort of file. It's code is slightly finished, but the question here is, how am I going to render and internally program this?

Here's what it is supposed to do:

1- The main idea is to make a class called **Block** which is the *base unit* of the environment. Every block is a 32x32x32 (or probably 64x64x64) cube which has a texture for every of its sides, or, some sort of *polygon* built in another yet unspecific way. Blocks also have an Opacity, Luminosity, HasGravity, IsMoveable/IsMovable/IsMobile, and IsEditable fields which determine it's properties.

2- It has an **Entity** class which is like an *object or a living thing* which is present in the map but *is not* part of it. I suppose this will requiere actual 3D models not built by the system. Has X, Y and Z Location/Size fields too. They have things like gravity, but not many physics are required right now *The Player is an Entity.*

3- It has a **Map** class which has the fields X, Y and Z sizes. This is intended to make the map build a specific amount of Blocks in a cube-like way. This class also has a triple array of Block, which is used to access Blocks by their position. Has many setting fields like boolean RenderSky or AllowTerrainEdit (by the player). If the map's Y limiting blocks are Void (a class of Block which represents void), and the map's RenderSky boolean equals true, then the map must render some sort of sky thing as their texture, or maybe render Sky in a better way?

4- The **Camera** class is a special type of entity which is works as a tool to determine what is rendered. In case the player is using first-person mode, for example, the camera would always be very nearby to (or maybe IN) the Player. The camera is allowed to be anywhere but inside solid blocks. The camera is not visible.

4- The graphics do not have to be that good yet, but this system's purpose is to make the map totally flexible and friendly to code (For example, if the player ever wanted to try some sort of sandbox styled actions like replacing part of the map for another material, the code would be able to do it all. It also makes map creation very friendly for both developers and users, requiring no code or 3D knowledge). Any other ideas rather than dividing the world into several cubes with a big selection of fields could also work.

I have no idea how to continue now. This is the only part the game is missing.

Useful facts:

- The game is sort of a simulator which tries to create a semi-real world, meaning its planned to have terrific, realistic things (like the real world's time system, NPCs with AI based on if(boolean) statements, physics...) with several update() voids, so it may result good to think in *performance*
- Maps are intended to be about 200+ blocks high (at least for the main map) and about an almost endless amount of blocks long and wide. Maybe this won't be possible. The good part is that the rendered content is the only thing that may lower performance, and it's not necessary to calculate rendering everything, just the Camera's view.
- Currently made purely with the Java programming language.
- I believe it could be useful to use the *OpenGL tool* here.

Thanks for reading all that. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [Lightweight Java Game Library](http://www.lwjgl.org/)?

> The Lightweight Java Game Library (LWJGL) is a solution aimed directly at professional and amateur Java programmers alike to enable commercial quality games to be written in Java. LWJGL provides developers access to high performance crossplatform libraries such as OpenGL (Open Graphics Library), OpenCL (Open Computing Language) and OpenAL (Open Audio Library) allowing for state of the art 3D games and 3D sound. Additionally LWJGL provides access to controllers such as Gamepads, Steering wheel and Joysticks. All in a simple and straight forward API.